# Why de-indenting after for loop consumed less memory in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I was solving a problem in python on HackerEarth to shift the elements of a list. I used the following code:

```
for _ in range(int(input())):
    n,sd=map(int,input().split())
    ls=input().split()
    print(" ".join(ls[n-(sd%n):]+ls[:n-(sd%n)]))
    print("\n")
```

I observed that the memory consumption was more in the above code as compared to the following code (which is completely similar, but I added a new line with a whitespace at the end) :

```
for _ in range(int(input())):
    n,sd=map(int,input().split())
    ls=input().split()
    print(" ".join(ls[n-(sd%n):]+ls[:n-(sd%n)]))
    print("\n")
 #a space here
```

Why this happened? I am attaching the screen snips.

[This is the code for first case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYP2A.png)

[The results for first code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2jr0.png)

[The code for second condition (containing space)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8s3jl.png)

[The results after adding a space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVAA0.png)

PS: This is the first time I am asking a question on stackoverflow, constructive criticisms are appreciated.

[image: I tried it multiple times!]

Comment: And when you remove the space, the memory consumption goes back up again?

Comment: yes, I tried it many times.

Comment: I'm guessing the tool running your code is just bad at measuring memory consumption. Perhaps it's snapshotting at intervals, and just happens to miss it sometimes, but not others. Point is, the extra space is meaningless to Python, and to any sane Python interpreter; most likely it's a fluke/bad measurement tool. If the results seem consistent, it may be that the tool doing the measurement doesn't rerun identical code, and just returns the old measurement; the extra space fools it.

Comment: That would be my interpretation as well. And "going back up" could relate to the tool caching previous results instead of measuring again. Also 64 KB is unreasonably low for a Python process, so I would doubt the lower number is even remotely correct.

Comment: I don't really know python's architecture but my guess is that python does some things to know that this is the end of a loop (or any indentations) as you know some languages have semicolon or curly braces. I've seen in my editor that at the end of each for loop that is the last line of my code it adds and extra line automatically I assume it's got to do something with cache (and maybe runtime).

Comment: you in your case does your code pass all the test cases or just few one, if all then memory consumption will be high and if only few cases it will be low, i think this is case with the 64 kb

Comment: @KuroshGhanizadeh: The extra spaces do nothing at runtime. The first thing the Python interpreter does is convert the source code to bytecode, and that conversion would immediately render both versions of the code to identical bytecode. The bytecode is what it actually runs. The incremental cost of parsing a few extra spaces during bytecode compilation is effectively zero.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: Thanks for your response. That was something I didn't know.